# Can't get PIC 16F876 working.What am I doing wrong?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

I have been playing around with the [PIC16F628](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010209) for a while, and now I want to transfer to something that has more pins. Specifically the [PIC16F876](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/devices.aspx?ddocname=en010239), but I can't get it working. I just want to turn an LED on/off and nothing ever happens. This is my circuit:

[image: PIC 16F987 circuit]

I program my PICs in the mikroC editor and these are the settings:

- OSCILLATOR: **HS**
- WATCHDOG: **Disabled**
- POWER-UP TIMER: **Disabled**
- FLASH code protection: **Disabled**
- Brown-out reset: **Enabled**
- Low voltage programming: **Disabled**
- Flash program memory write: **Enabled**
- In-circuit debug: **Disabled**

And this is my code:

```
void main(){
    TRISB = 0x00;
    while(1){
        PORTB = 0b11111111;
        delay_ms(500);
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

And nothing works. I tried with 4.10 and 11 MHz oscillator values
and nothing. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I assume "nothing works" means the LED does not even lit? Did you define your clock (something like _#define F_CPU 10000000L_) for 10MHz? The _delay_ works from that definition. Though, you say it is 500ms, it might be longer/shorter. Can RB7 pin deliver enough current for the LED? You might need some buffer. Did you choose the correct resistor?

Comment: Silly thought perhaps, but is the LED the right way around?

Comment: ... Decoupling?

Comment: As Dzarda said, one likely cause is that your circuit is missing decoupling caps. Put a ceramic 100 nF capacitor as close as possible to the 20(VDD) and 19(VSS) pins of the uC and try again.

Comment: Did you include the proper header files? These define things like TRIS, PORT, delay_ms, etc. I would expect the header files to be named something like p16f876.h and delays.h. They should be located in your compiler's installation directory. See this link: http://www.mikroe.com/download/eng/documents/compilers/mikroc/pro/pic/help/file_inclusion.htm

Comment: Does the program compile?

Comment: To address the comments: 1. I don't need to define something like <p16f876> or <delays> because Mikroc has and editor to set the PIC settings and delays have always worked without definition in previous projects. 2. LED is most definitely not oriented wrong and resistor value is correct. 3. Even if pins cant deliver enough current for the LED there is no current whatsoever present on the pins. 4. I have included decoupling capacitors and still no result.

Comment: Does one need ANSELB=0 on that PIC?

Comment: I seem to recall that some PICs have ports configured as analog input after reset. Try ANSELB=0.

Comment: Is the pin high, low or high-Z? Check with a resistor to Vdd/Vss. Maybe try another pin, that one is shared with debug which you think you've turned off, but still..

Comment: Also, can you see oscillation at pin 10?

Comment: I tried your code with all your settings on a 16F876 and it worked perfectly - even without a decoupling capacitor. Assuming your chip is not fried, the only thing I can think of is a wiring error.

Answer (score 7):

With the bypass cap missing, nothing else matters.

I'd also move the LED off of RB6 or RB7 since those are the programming and debugging lines.  You won't be able to use either of those pins while debugging.  RB5 is a good choice.  I don't understand why you'd use a pin multiplexed with anything else when all you're trying to do is test that code is running by seeing a LED blink.

Tie the PGM pin (RB3) to ground.

Don't forget to clear the TRIS bit for the pin you are using.

Test the code in the simulator first.  There's no point trying it on hardware until the basic code is working correctly.